# Unordered list bullet items are not displaying when using prose-lg class but working fine when I am using just prose class in Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-3

In my blog page I am using markdown and Tailwind. For unordered list, bullet points are not displaying when I am using **prose-lg** class. But, it is working fine when I am using just **prose** class.

##### When I am using prose class this is the output

[image]

[image]

##### When I am using prose-lg class this is the output ( I need to use prose-lg class, as the font is small in prose class )

[image]

[image]

Please help me with this issue. Also I have seen that, in `assets/node_modules/@tailwindcss/typography/src/index.test.js` file  `.prose ul > li::before` having `content: \\"\\";` but in `.prose-lg ul > li::before` it doesn't have it. Do I need to do anything here?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer to this question in Tailwind CSS discussion forum. `prose-lg` class alone is not enough , we also need to add `prose` class along with `prose-lg`. Below is the link of discussion: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/5822